# Error in my vast xml?

Tags: xml, vast

I have very little experience with vast but I need to learn fast.
Right now I'm writing a vast file that will do a waterfall between several vast urls.
Now it's the beginning so I put only one partner tag.

But when I test it in the [google vast inspector](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/vastinspector), it fails:

> AdError 1010: The ad response was not understood and cannot be parsed.

I checked several examples on the web [like this one](http://demo.tremorvideo.com/proddev/vast/vast_wrapper_linear_1.xml) in order to reproduce it, I don't understand what I did wrong. Can you help me please ?

Thank you so much !

Comment: And why you don't show us yours VAST?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce AdError 1010, but there are two obvious issues with this tag http://demo.tremorvideo.com/proddev/vast/vast_wrapper_linear_1.xml
All URIs must be wrapped in CDATA blocks and Google's VAST inspector requires HTTPS which is not supported it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Google vast inspector doesn't accepted my vast structure.
[Here is an example that is successfully parsed by Google](https://gist.github.com/VivienAdnot/c5a9727eefbc873bcfa410f5592269c4)